# How to create MetaTable from Entity Framework table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data, metatable

How to create MetaTable from Entity Framework table or context? I am using code-first.

This is intended for use with some DynamicData methods

Comment: What do you want is after create the table you want to insert metadata to it?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few parts to this one:

On startup, make sure to register the dynamic data provider in global.asax

Global.asax.cs / other

```
App.DefaultModel.RegisterContext(
             new Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.ModelProviders.EFDataModelProvider(() => new MyDbContext()),
             new ContextConfiguration { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

App.cs ( a static class I use to store permanent references )

```
public static class App

  ...

   private static MetaModel s_defaultModel = new MetaModel();

   public static MetaModel DefaultModel
      {get{ return s_defaultModel; }}
}
```

where you need it

```
ModelMetaTable meta = App.DefaultModel.GetTable( nameof(db.MyAwsomeName) );
```

then you can do things like

```
MyAwesomeForm.SetMetaTable(table);
```

and the form will have all user controls like its in a normal dynamic data website